# Match a list col in R

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors and I want to get the index in the list where a value is in the vector. I've tried using `match()` but it returns NA if the vector has a length greater than one.

For example `match("a", list(c("a", "b"), c("c")))` returns `NA` but I would need it to return `1`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%in%`

```
 which(sapply(mylist, function(x) 'a' %in% x))
[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we could use `purrr` package functions. (Using @maydin's sample data and thanks for that):

```
library(purrr)

imap(mylist, ~ if("a" %in% .x) .y) %>%
  discard(is.null)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep:

```
grep("a",list(c("a", "b"), c("c")))
```

which gives

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

`match` works. first `unlist`

```
match("a", unlist(list(c("a", "b"), c("c"))))
```

Output:

```
> match("a", unlist(list(c("a", "b"), c("c"))))
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply()` to get the index of the vector inside the list,

```
which(!is.na(sapply(mylist ,function(x) match("a",x))))

#[1] 1 3
```

**Data:**

```
   mylist <- list(c("a", "b"), c("c"),c("d","e","f","a"))
```

Comment: Thanks - but this returns where the value is in the vector rather than which vector it is in in the list